# I want some help in populating a tree structure on my webpage from flat structure without Parent/child values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a dynamic tree structure from the JSON response i receive. The JSON is as follows:

```
var projectViewData = [{
        "projectTYpe": "Report",
        "Doctor": "Abc",
        "Patient": null,
        "type": "xyz",
        "document":"a.xls"
    },{
        "projectTYpe": "Report",
        "Doctor": "Abc",
        "Patient": "Smith",
        "type": "xyz",
        "document":"a.xls"
    },

{
        "projectTYpe": "Analysis",
        "Doctor": "Abc",
        "Patient": null,
        "type": "xyz",
        "document":"a.xls"
    },
{
        "projectTYpe": "Report",
        "Doctor": "Abc",
        "Patient": "Smith",
        "type": "xyz",
        "document":"a.xls"
    }
    ];
```

The JSON can have null values which need to be ignored and next value from the object needs to be picked to plot next in the tree. The Object also don't have parent_id/child_id. My approach is to iterate through every object in json and adding it to an array.

This is the final structure I want to be dynamically generated on my page using javascript.
[image]

Below is the work i have done till now.

```
 var array = ["<ul class=\"tree\">"];

 for (projectdataElem in projectViewData)
 {
 array.push("<ul>");
var count = 0;
for (x in projectViewData[projectdataElem])
    {


    if(projectViewData[projectdataElem][x]==null )
{ 

}
else
{ if(x=='document'){
    array.push("<li>" + projectViewData[projectdataElem][x] + "</li>");
    for(var i = 0; i< count; i++)
        {
          array.push("</ul>"); }
}
else{
    if((array.indexOf(projectViewData[projectdataElem][x]))== -1){
        console.log(array.indexOf(projectViewData[projectdataElem][x]));
        console.log(projectViewData[projectdataElem][x]);
 //array.push("<li>" + projectViewData[projectdataElem][x] + "</li>");
 array.push("<li>");
 array.push(projectViewData[projectdataElem][x]);
 array.push("</li>");
 array.push("<ul>");
 count += 1;
 }
}
}
    }

 array.push("</ul>");




     }
 array.push("</ul>");
 $("#list1").html(array.join(""));
//printList("string");
console.log(array);
```

Any leads would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Java is not Javascript. Please make an effort to figure out which language you want to write code in.

Comment: Sorry about the wrong tag. Can you help me build this using javascript?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Please read the [How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am appending my code now.